# scrolled window border

Tags: border, gtkmm, scrolledwindow

In Gtkmm how to remove the inset border from a scrolled window?I used a scrolled window that holds a image widget.The scrolled window itself appears within a Hbox.An inset border appears around the window which i want to remove.How?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get rid of that using the `Gtk::ScrolledWindow` method `set_shadow_type(Gtk::SHADOW_NONE)`

Comment: Apologies. I have an app that has a clean scrolling area, but I didn't keep good enough notes on this aspect, and it's not clear from the code what else is needed.

Comment: ScrolledWindow inserts a ViewPort object for classes that don't implement their own scrolling.  You can try getting a hold of that and setting it's shadow type.  This is just a guess though.